# Cannot read property 'length' in pug / jade

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to make an "each" inside my pug code, but after running the app I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

This is my pug template code:

```
extends ../templates/default

block content
  - var item = [];
  form.post(action='http://localhost:3000/users/panel', method='post')
    img.avatar(src='/img/avatar.jpg', alt='')
    input(type='text', name='post', value='', placeholder='Escribe algo')
    input(type='submit', value='Publicar')
  #card-container
    .card
      img.avatar(src='/img/avatar.jpg', alt='')
      .name='@'+user.nombre
      .date='id='+user.id
      p.card='Hi!'
  table
    thead
      tr
        th # pub
        th # user
        th Publicacion
    tbody
      each item in items
        tr
          td=item.id_publicacion
          td=item.id_user
          td=item.publicacion
```

This is my controller:

```
getPubs: function(req, res, next) {
    var config = require('.././database/config');
    var db = mysql.createConnection(config);

    db.query('SELECT * FROM publicaciones', function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.render('panel', {
            items: rows
        });
    });
}
```

And finally this is the router (where I make the call):

```
router.get('/users/pubs', controllers.UserController.getPubs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling "panel" in the render but it looks like is into "users" so you have to put this:

```
getPubs: function(req, res, next) {
    var config =require('.././database/config');
    var db = mysql.createConnection(config);

    db.query('SELECT * FROM publicaciones', function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.render('users/panel', {
            items: rows
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have error in your mysql connection. Could you add error handler to your controler like this:

```
getPubs: function(req, res, next) {
    var config =require('.././database/config');
    var db = mysql.createConnection(config);

    db.query('SELECT * FROM publicaciones', function(err, rows, fields)
{
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send({err: err});
    }

    res.render('panel', {
        items: rows
    });
});
}
```